# Prompt website user if there is app for that

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, frontend

Is there a way to prompt user to install app for that particular website?

To simplify, if you visit website from Android phone you see alert that there is an app on Google Play for that website. Same for iPhone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS apps you can use [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

Just add the AppStoreID to this meta tag in the head of page:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Comment: Is there an android equivalent of this?